# How to perform routing relative to parent module in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working on an Angular2 application with @ngrx and @ngrx/router-store for routing actions.

I am trying to restructure the application to try to follow module routing guidelines described in the guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#crisis-child-routes

The application I am building allows for the user to log into accounts for a particular 'location'.  Once the user logs in, the URL contains the current location as the start, similar to the user/account showing when logging into Gmail: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/`

Here is the general outline of the routes:

```
/login
/location/:id                 <-- LocationModule/LocationRoutingModule
/location/:id/home            <-- HomeModule/HomeRoutingModule
/location/:id/calendars       <-- CalendarModule/CalendarRoutingModule
/location/:id/calendars/:cid
/location/:id/clients         <-- ClientModule/ClientRoutingModule
/location/:id/clients/:cid
/location/:id/clients/:cid/...
```

Now, I'd like for the individual feature modules (Home, Calendar, Client) to not have to know "where they reside" in the route (i.e. they don't know if they exist as a child of  '/' or '/location/:id'.

This is fine so long as there are no routes between features.  However, there are cases where it will be necessary to navigate between feature areas/modules(I am trying to minimize these).  For example, there is a link on the "home" component that should route to a calendar.

The only ideas I have are (neither of which I particularly like):

- A service provided at the `LocationModule` level that the child modules use for routing:
- An @ngrx effect "outside" the `HomeModule` that triggers on action "SELECT_CALENDAR" and knows about the correct "base" route to use to route to the calendar feature area

Is there any other clean way to implement this?  A different module structure/hierarchy?

If not, any arguments for or against my two potential implementations?  Suggestions for how to best go about implementing?

Thanks